# In the following c program if condition is not working

Tags: c, if-statement, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main()
{
    int iRandom;
    int iResponse;
    srand(time(0));

    iRandom = (rand() % 10) + 1;

    printf("\nGuess a number between 1 and 10: ");
    scanf("%c", &iResponse);

    if (isdigit(iResponse)) {

        iResponse = iResponse - '0';

        if (iResponse >=1 && iResponse <=10 ) {


            if (iResponse == iRandom) {
                printf("\nYou guessed right.\n");
            }
            else {
                printf("\nSorry, you guessed wrong.\n");
                printf("The correct guess was %d\n", iRandom);
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("You did not enter a digit between 1 and 10.");
        }

    }
    else {
        printf("\nYou did not enter a digit.\n");
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Check this out condition if (iResponse >=1 && iResponse <=10 ) is not working.
in this condition if iResponse <= 10 is false then it will not execute the else part.
Any Solution plz help me.

Comment: `int iResponse;` => `char iResponse;`

Comment: `main()` --> `int main(void)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main( void )
{
    char line[20];
    unsigned int iRandom;
    unsigned int iResponse;

    const unsigned int Base = 10;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    iRandom = rand() % Base + 1;

    printf( "\nGuess a number between 1 and %u: ", Base );
    scanf( "%20s", line );

    errno = 0;
    iResponse = ( unsigned int )strtoul( line, NULL, Base );

    if ( !errno && iResponse >= 1 && iResponse <=10 ) 
    {
        if ( iResponse == iRandom ) 
        {
            puts( "\nYou guessed right." );
        }
        else 
        {
            puts( "\nSorry, you guessed wrong." );
            printf( "The correct guess was %u\n", iRandom );
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        puts( "\nYou did not enter a number" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program outputs might look the following way

```
Guess a number between 1 and 10: A
You did not enter a number

Guess a number between 1 and 10: 4
Sorry, you guessed wrong.
The correct guess was 3

Guess a number between 1 and 10: 4
You guessed right.
```

As for your code then at least in this statement

```
scanf("%c", &iResponse);
```

you should substitute `"%c"` to `" %c"` (a blank before %c). Though even in this case the result will be implementation defined. And moreover using this approach you will be unable to enter acceptable number `10`.:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
 scanf("%c", &iResponse);
```

When you enter for example 47 as a input it just take 4 not 47 it just read one character which is '4' . '47' is not a character. So it will always enter that condition whenever you enter some number. But if you try to enter 'a' as a input it will return you

```
You did not enter a digit
```

You can make it work with the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main()
{
    int iRandom;
    int iResponse;
    srand(time(0));

    iRandom = (rand() % 10) + 1;

    printf("\nGuess a number between 1 and 10: ");
    scanf("%d", &iResponse);

    if (isdigit(iResponse+'0') || iResponse==10) {



        if (iResponse >=1 && iResponse <=10 ) {


            if (iResponse == iRandom) {
                printf("\nYou guessed right.\n");
            }
            else {
                printf("\nSorry, you guessed wrong.\n");
                printf("The correct guess was %d\n", iRandom);
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("You did not enter a digit between 1 and 10.");
        }

    }
    else {
        printf("\nYou did not enter a digit.\n");
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 47 cant be input. It is mentioned that input should between 1 to 10.

Comment: Check this out condition if (iResponse >=1 && iResponse <=10 ) is not working. in this condition if iResponse <= 10 is false then it will not execute the else part. Any Solution plz help me. From this it is obvious that he also checks that part so the important thing it will enter that loop even if he enters 47 which is false .

Comment: @MIRMIX you explained it right. Some genius has downvoted you and me.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
scanf("%c", &iResponse);

if (isdigit(iResponse)) {
    . . .
```

to

```
if (scanf("%d", &iResponse)) {
    . . .
```

A working code will then look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    int iRandom = (rand() % 10) + 1, iResponse;
    printf("\nGuess a number between 1 and 10: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &iResponse)) {
        if (iResponse >= 1 && iResponse <= 10 ) {
            if (iResponse == iRandom)
                printf("\nYou guessed right.\n");
            else 
                printf("\nSorry, The correct guess was %d\n", iRandom);
        }
        else
            printf("You did not enter a number between 1 and 10.");
    }
    else
        printf("\nYou did not enter a number.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
1
```

**Sample Output**

```
Sorry, The correct guess was 9
```

See a demo http://ideone.com/V7GIeK.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you declared `iResponse` as `integer` variable and in `scanf` you wrote specifier as `%c` that is character.

```
scanf("%c", &iResponse);
```

Just change to-

```
scanf("%d", &iResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a good aproach of your program i think you wanna check the user imput to be sure that it is the one you are expecting for.
This means that you need to check if the Input does include only Numbers.
Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define RANDOM 10

void clean_stdin(void){
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != 0 && c != '\n');
}

int inputCheck(void){
    int number;
    char c;

    do{
        printf("\tPlease type a Number: ");
        if (scanf("%d%c", &number, &c) == 0 || c != '\n'){
            printf("\nLetter[s] was Found in your Answear\n\n\n");
            clean_stdin();
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }while(TRUE);

    return number;
}

int main(void){
    int iResponse;
    int iRandom ;
    srand ( (unsigned int)time(NULL) );

    iRandom = (rand() % 10 + 1);
    iResponse = inputCheck();

    if(iRandom == iResponse){
        printf("\nYou guessed right.\n");
    }else{
        printf( "\nSorry, you guessed wrong.\n" );
        printf( "\n\t\t\tThe correct guess was %u\n", iRandom );
    }

    return(0);
}
```

And you will get:

> ```
>   Please type a Number: 3r
> ```

```
Letter[s] was Found in your Answear


    Please type a Number: G7

Letter[s] was Found in your Answear


    Please type a Number: 6

Sorry, you guessed wrong.

            The correct guess was 4
```

> ```
>   Please type a Number: 4
> ```

```
You guessed right.
```

With this aproach you can inform the User about his/her Input.

If you wanna inform User that the number is between 1 and 10 you do like this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define MIN_RANDOM 1
#define Max_RANDOM 10

void clean_stdin(void){
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != 0 && c != '\n');
}

int inputCheck(int min, int max){
    int number;
    char c;

    do{
    printf("\tPlease type a Number::\t");
    if (scanf("%d%c", &number, &c) == 0 || c != '\n'){
        clean_stdin();
        printf("\nLetter[s] was Found in your Answear\n\n\n");
    }else if(number < min || number > max){
        printf("The number has to be wetween %d and %d\n\n",min, max);
    }else{
        break;
    }
    }while(TRUE);

    return number;
}

int main(void){
    int iResponse;
    int iRandom ;
    srand ( (unsigned int)time(NULL) );

    iRandom = (rand() % Max_RANDOM + MIN_RANDOM);
    iResponse = inputCheck(MIN_RANDOM,Max_RANDOM);

    if(iRandom == iResponse){
    printf("\nYou guessed right.\n");
    }else{
    printf( "\nSorry, you guessed wrong.\n" );
    printf( "\n\t\t\tThe correct guess was %u\n", iRandom );
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Output will be something like this:

> ```
>   Please type a Number::  A1
> ```

```
Letter[s] was Found in your Answear


    Please type a Number::  1A

Letter[s] was Found in your Answear


    Please type a Number::  15
The number has to be wetween 1 and 10

    Please type a Number::  4

Sorry, you guessed wrong.

            The correct guess was 8
```

Answer (score -2):

Try making

```
char iResponse;
```

See this worked

[image]

[image]